# Lightning Connector Power Output rating/ Apple Policy

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, iphone, output

I am currently in the process of developing an external antenna for smartphones, so the answer of the following question(s) pertains to the feasibility of this product.

What is the line level output from a lightning connector, and is there a limit placed by apple?

After doing some research on this forum I found that the Lightning connector outputs a maximum of 100maH at 3.3V....is this correct? Does Apple limit the amount of power output by its phones?

Sincerest Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: What is a "lightning connector"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector) apple is funny

Comment: I'm curious ... What exactly do you mean by "external antenna"?

Comment: Maybe he means a sort of active repeater.

Comment: Lightning cables can carry multiple Amps of power. As for iPhone/iPad output to accessories, as of like ios 4 its been limited to 50mA (down from 100mA) (from hacking the camera connector kit), and more importantly, lightning devices require authentication.